# Getting same price for RDS Reserved Instance at 1yr or 3yr

Tags: amazon-rds

I was looking at pricing some reserved instances for one of our organisation's mssql DBs. When I head into the console the appropriate options, such as product (sqlserver-se), size (m5.xlarge), etc, Amazon is giving the same price for an upfront payment for 1yr & 3yr!

I'm baffled. As a test, if I select a small instance, with mssql-web it does change the price when I change between 1 & 3 yrs.

Anyone know what might be happening? I don't see any other options on the page.

Screenshot attached. [image] [image]

Comment: Per https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/pricing/, `db.m5.large` (and all the other `m5` generation instances) only has one year terms listed. I do see three year terms for `db.m4` instances; I suspect they're doing away with the longer option in more recent generations.

Comment: Ah I see. That was quite puzzling. They really should display a message to say 3 yr is unavailable rather than allow selection. Thanks a million @ceejayoz!

Comment: @ceejayoz - if you put that into an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I am curious about what happens if you purchase a three year term via the UI - whether it just drops down to a one year, or if you wind up buying three sequential. You're right - it should grey out the three year option if you select an `m5` instance.

Comment: Same here - I'm a but if a chicken giving the up front payment involved ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/pricing, `db.m5.large` (and all the other `m5` generation instances) only has one year terms listed. I do see three year terms for `db.m4` instances; I suspect they're doing away with the longer option in more recent generations.